# MVC Conventional and Attribute routing not working together

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I am using conventional routing on an ASP.Net MVC project and would like to enable Attribute routing in parallel. I have created the following but I am getting a 404 on the conventional route when enabling attribute routing

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Controller

```
[RoutePrefix("Registration")]
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Add/{eventId}")]
    public ActionResult Add(int eventId)
    {
    }
}
```

Calling

```
http://localhost/Registration/Add/1
```

Works, while calling

```
http://localhost/Registration/Add?eventId=1
```

No longer works and responds with *404 NotFound*

Comment: Your controller is called `RegistrationController`, so, with convention based routing, its route is: `http://localhost/Registration/Add` and not `http:/localhost/Register/Add`

Comment: Sorry that's a typo and misleading, I've updated the code. The controller should be marked with a [RoutePrefix()] whereas before I had it as simply [Route()]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Both of Attribute and Convention Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406985/using-both-of-attribute-and-convention-routing)

Comment: So it sounds like I can only use one or the other? The idea was to keep the Conventional routing to preserve bookmarks etc, but to gradually switch users over to the attribute-based links

Comment: It seems that any "direct route" (action with at least one `Route` attribute) removes that action from the conventional routing. A workaround could be to define different `Route` attributes, to keep the old behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Should work if you make the `{eventId}` template parameter optional in the route template

```
[RoutePrefix("Registration")]
public class RegistrationController : Controller {
    //GET Registration/Add/1
    //GET Registration/Add?eventId=1
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Add/{eventId:int?}")]
    public ActionResult Add(int eventId) {
        //...
    }
}
```

The reason the two were not working is that the route template `Add/{eventId}` means that the route will only match if the `{eventId}` is present, which is why

```
http://localhost/Registration/Add/1
```

works.

By making it (`eventId`) optional `eventid?` it will allow

```
http://localhost/Registration/Add
```

to work as the template parameter is not required. This will now allow query string `?eventId=1` to be used, which the routing table will use to match the `int eventId` parameter argument on the action.

```
http://localhost/Registration/Add?eventId=1
```

Comment: This sort of works for me. If I have an Action with two parameters for example   public ActionResult Information(int? personId, string level = ""){}  then calling http://localhost:54659/Registration/Information?personId=5592 doesn't work.    Is the problem in my RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: @Adrian is that action using attribute routing as well?

Comment: Basically every controller action that works with conventional routing, I would like to extend it to use attribute routing in parallel. So i need the "old style" to work while I migrate people to the attribute routing

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue. Which MVC version are you using? 
I faced this issue with MVC in asp.net core. 
I think this is a flaw as if you provide Routing attribute on any action method, its conventional route is over ridden and is not longer available so you get 404 error. 
For this to work, you can provide another Route attribute to your action method like this. This will work

```
 [Route("Add/{eventId}")]  
 [Route("Add")]
```